# How to add metadata to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, metadata

I'm very new to Sharepoint and I'm asked to add a metadata to a file. 
When you are in a document library you see a lots of uploaded files. the have a type, name, modified and modified by meta data. I would like to add a new metadata field. But I don't know how. 
I've downloaded the Microsoft Sharepoint Designer.

And once the have the extra metadata field is added it to needs be filled via the querystring. I found something about that on the Internet, but where I have to add the javascript I don't know, so any help with that would be very appriciated.

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add fields like type, name, modified and modified by  ? and it should be filled

by the uset at the time of upload?

If yes, then you dont have to use javascript or something like that

Just create a new column in the list or library by folllowing the steps given below:

Go to your list or library and click on Library in ribbon

click on list Settings,

Find Create new columns.. Follow the steps and click ok

It will create new field(metadata) in your list / library

Let  me know if I wrongly understand your question